# border-bottom not going across completely

Tags: css

I have a subnav that has a border-bottom under each of the sub menu items, when I was checking to see if it was ok in all the browsers I noticed that the border-bottom stopped where the text ended in IE7.

Here is my css

```
.subnav_wrapper_ul {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AEEF;
font-size: 13px !important;
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.header-wrapper .main-nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 1000;
}
.subnav_wrapper_ul li {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
float: none !important;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

if there is anything else that you need from me please let me know

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle with your html and css

Comment: How would putting the code on jsFiddle help if everything looks fine on all the other browsers except for IE7

Comment: Because it's a tool we use to see how people are setting up their code. We cannot see the issue, so you need to provide a live example using jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Give the **border-bottom** css property to the **ul** element , instead of the individual **li** items.

```
.subnav_wrapper_ul {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AEEF;
font-size: 13px !important;
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
z-index: 1000;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: If I do that then the border-bottom is at the bottom of the subnav wrapper instead of below each menu item

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any link or any image for reference, so in this case we all have to guess.

anyway you are talking about submenu section. can we use a IE7 specific hack here..

```
*:first-child+html .subnav_wrapper_ul li {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
float: none !important;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Another way to target IE7 is:

```
*border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
```